# how can I use youtube api thumbnails in PHP?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to change form load in this youtube api to be youtube with thumbnail, so that how can I change it? thank you in advanced of your helping.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO this is a site for Q&A about coding problems. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck in your code? SO is not about requesting code

Comment: why is android tagged in this ??

Answer (score 0):

If by "youtube with thumbnail" you mean the thumbnail of any youtube video, then a simple way to get that is to call the url `http://img.youtube.com/vi/ + $VideoId + /0.jpg`.